# Popover adapt to content size IOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

I have simple popover on iPhone:

[image: Popover]

I would like to have its size be as "content size" of popup - ending just below add button. Can I make it happen by using auto layout? I would prefer not to change width of this popover, just height. I have tried to use prefferedContentSize for View inside, but it was then too small. 
I tried to do this by auto layout, and it did not work.

This is how it looks in storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Can I see the code you used when you tried `preferredContentSize`? That would be how I would do it, so I am curious how you tried it.

Comment: Hi! I tried with some constants that I was thinking will be ok.

Comment: You should be able to calculate the width and height of all the views inside the popover and return that as the preferred content size.

Comment: @keithbhunter But I have to do it after everything is layed on screen, yes? I think width is tricky in this case, since it is set by framework. Like I said. I want to adjust height only;)

Comment: You could set the property in `viewWillApear`, that way the frames will be set. You can probably find what the default width is by breakpointing before you set the property and use that default width. Then you just calculate the height.

Comment: @keithbhunter I tried in viewdidlayoutsubviews to make sure. I would like to accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the width and height of the views in the popover (or use the default width in this case) in `viewWillAppear(_:)` and use that to set the `preferredContentSize` of the view controller. Waiting till `viewWillAppear(_:)` is important so the frames are set.